# Does molecular diffraction depend on slit size?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Large molecules (phtalocyanine derivatives) moving at 100 m/s are able to pass through a grating in a wave-like manner and to diffract behind the grating. Are the molecules in this wavelike state able to pass through slits that are smaller than the size (diameter) of the molecule?

(This question is about the size of a molecule compared to the width of a single slit, not the distance between two slits)

Comment: Related: [Does the internal state of a particle change after tunneling?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483265/21441)